How to configure clang-format for multi-line template parameters?
I'm mostly indenting the multi-line template parameters as below.
// clang-format off
struct Pretty {
    std::vector<
        std::pair<
            size_t,
            std::vector<float>
        >
    > value;

    size_t destinationID;
};
// clang-format on

But, I couldn't achieve such a format using the clang-format. Is there a way of doing it?
struct Ugly {
    std::vector<
    std::pair<
    size_t,
    std::vector<float>
    >>
    value;

    size_t destinationID;
};

I'm using clang-format v20.0.0

Create a typedef to avoid the problem entirely.

@Wyck I couldn't get it

I agree with @wyck.  using some_name = ...;, some_name value;

Also do not use std::pair just regular struct. When you give names to fields and this struct it will be easier to read the code (understand intent).

Here is an example what Wyck meant: https://godbolt.org/z/fqe8vefr6 May look like a boiler plate, but when you have to do some corrections in code this style of coding pays of a lot.

@MarekR Oh, great! Thanks.

Re original question, I don't think clang-format or any other reasonable formatter has available options to set up such specific newline/indent, precisely because best practices are to avoid it entirely so there's no real demand on devs. Uncrustify can at least do progressively deeper indents.
